# Is it possible to start playing audio from the background when a geofence is entered/exited?

Tags: android, ios, audio, geolocation

I'm having trouble determining if iOS and/or Android has the capability of starting audio playback from the background.  The general order of operations would be...

1. User starts app
2. User chooses to hear audio when they arrive/depart a location
3. Region monitoring is used in the background to determine location changes
4. Region is entered/exited: if the app is configured to play certain audio for this region, load it from a URL and start playing it.  If another track is already playing, queue the new one.
5. If music/other audio is already playing in the background, duck it until my queue has completed

I know that I'll need to enable background audio, but I'm not able to determine if I can initiate playback from the background.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?